# How to select a value using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am new XML and struggling to find an answer to this problem. I have the following code (see below) and would like to extract the value 3400.0000000000 from it.

How do I do this using Xpath?

```
<SpindleSpeed dataItemId="c2" name="Sspeed" sequence="351828725" subType="ACTUAL" timestamp="2014-12-01T21:51:32.834494">3400.0000000000</SpindleSpeed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
//SpindleSpeed/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath has two parts - locations paths and functions. A location path will always return a list of nodes (an empty one if it can not find a matching node).

Here are three possible location paths in your XML:

`/SpindleSpeed` for the SpindleSpeed element node that is the document element

`//SpindleSpeed` for any SpindleSpeed element node in the document

`//SpindleSpeed/text()` for any text nodes inside any SpindleSpeed element node in the document

If you have a list you can cast it

`number(//SpindleSpeed)` is the content of the first node in the list (from the location path) as a number - 0.0 if the list was empty.

`string(//SpindleSpeed)` is the content of the first node in the list (from the location path) as a string - an empty string for an empty list.

Comment: Thanks you guys for your help, I have implemented your suggestions and it is working now. Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If X is an expression that selects the SpindleSpeed element, then string(X) is an expression that returns its string value, that is "3400.0000000000"